# DataContractJsonSerializer ReadObject return NULL value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, datacontract

I have problem to deserialize this JSON provided by a REST Web Service.
This is my suggestion to resolve the problem

```
class Program
{       
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RestResponse r = readFromWeb("http://www.808.dk/?code-csharp-httpwebrequest");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static RestResponse readFromWeb(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        Stream webStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RestResponse));
        RestResponse resttresponse = (RestResponse)json.ReadObject(webStream);
        return resttresponse;
    }
}
```

And the DataContract class

```
[DataContract]
public class RestResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<string> messages { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<City> result { get; set; }       
}
[DataContract]
public class City
{        
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string alpha2_code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string alpha3_code { get; set; }
}
```

Any suggestion?
Cordially.

Comment: Are you limited to using DataContractJsonSerializer ? using Newtonsoft.Json is much more easier and robust to use when working with JSON

Comment: No, but I am preparing for 70-483 examination, so i have to work with DataContractJsonSerializer. Thank you for your contribution and I will try to use Newtonsoft.json framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need Json object that hold RestResponse, take a look at this sample, it works:

```
  internal class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //var r = readFromWeb("http://www.808.dk/?code-csharp-httpwebrequest");
      var r = readFromWeb("http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all");
      Trace.Write(r);
    }

    private static MyJson readFromWeb(string url)
    {
      var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
      request.ContentType = "application/json";
      request.Method = "GET";
      var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
      var webStream = response.GetResponseStream();
      var json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (MyJson));
      var resttresponse = (MyJson) json.ReadObject(webStream);
      return resttresponse;
    }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class MyJson
  {
    [DataMember(Name = "RestResponse")]
    public RestResponse RestResponse { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class RestResponse
  {
    [DataMember(Name = "messages")]
    public string[] messages { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "result")]
    public City[] result { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class City
  {
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "alpha2_code")]
    public string alpha2_code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "alpha3_code")]
    public string alpha3_code { get; set; }
  }
```